# Is it possible to use UI Component with Custom Collection Data?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, backend, listing-component

I'm trying to create an admin grid with custom data that comes from an array, i tried creating a Custom Collection using addItem method from \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection, but i'm kind of stuck on how i can make it work with UI Component listing in the admin.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find the solution ?